# Pandas: select corresponding value columns based on minimum from key columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with column pairs x_1 & x_2 like:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A_1': [20, 30, 500],
        'A_2': [40, 60, 1000],
        'B_1': [35, 12, 600],
        'B_2': [70, 24, 1200],
    }
)
df

    A_1  A_2  B_1  B_2
0   20   40   35   70
1   30   60   12   24
2   500  1000 600  1200
```

The column pairs are stored in a dictionary.

```py
comp_cols = {
    'A_1': 'A_2',
    'B_1': 'B_2',
}
```

**Now, for every row I want to get the corresponding value from the value-column based on the minimum of the key-columns [A_1, B_1].**

Here is my "clumsy" solution.

```py
df['min_1_col'] = df[comp_cols.keys()].idxmin(axis=1)
df['min_2_val'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[comp_cols[x['min_1_col']]], axis=1)
df

    A_1  A_2   B_1  B_2   min_1_col  min_2_val
0   20   40    35   70    A_1        40
1   30   60    12   24    B_1        24
2   500  1000  600  1200  A_1        1000
```

Is there a clever way of doing this more elegantly without adding an auxiliary column?

Thanks!
carlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use numpy indexing to select from the DataFrame. We just need to convert [`idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html) to the associated column using [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) then [`get_indexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) from the columns to get indexes that work to select from the DataFrame [`values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html):

```
df['min_2_val'] = df.values[
    df.index,
    df.columns.get_indexer(df[comp_cols.keys()].idxmin(axis=1).map(comp_cols))
]
```

`df`:

```
   A_1   A_2  B_1   B_2  min_2_val
0   20    40   35    70         40
1   30    60   12    24         24
2  500  1000  600  1200       1000
```

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A_1': [20, 30, 500],
        'A_2': [40, 60, 1000],
        'B_1': [35, 12, 600],
        'B_2': [70, 24, 1200],
    }
)

comp_cols = {
    'A_1': 'A_2',
    'B_1': 'B_2',
}
```

Comment: Thanks Henry, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Use `stack` and `reindex`:

```
df['col'] = df.stack() \
              .reindex(df[comp_cols.keys()].idxmin(axis=1)
                                           .map(comp_cols)
                                           .reset_index().values) \
              .values
```

```
>>> df
   A_1   A_2  B_1   B_2   col
0   20    40   35    70    40
1   30    60   12    24    24
2  500  1000  600  1200  1000
```

Comment: @CarloP. I updated my solution. Can you check that if it's not already done, please?

Comment: Yes Corralien, your solution is working fine here! I think the solution below from Henry is even a bit easier to digest, but that's maybe just me. So thanks a lot for your proposal!